# Visual Basic wmic Formatting Error

Tags: vb.net, formatting, wmic

Whenever I pipe `wmic` output from the `cmd` prompt to a text file, everything is formatted correctly. Whenever my application does the same thing (see code below) I get the same output, its just formatted incorrectly. Whats the correct process to do? I am using Visual Basic.

My variable, `commandList(i)`, is whatever command entered into the text box. So in this case something like `wmic CPU get Description`.

All the other commands I have tested work fine, its just the `WMIC` ones that are formatted incorrectly.

Here is the EXACT code.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Label6.Visible = False

    Me.Visible = False

    Dim s = New SplashScreen1()
    s.Show()
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1200)
    s.Close()

    Me.Visible = True


End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Visible = False


    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text) Then
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox2.Text) Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(RichTextBox1.Text) Then

                If (TextBox1.Text = "rbm-") Then

                    If (TextBox2.Text = "081491") Then

                        Dim commandList() As String
                        Dim i As Integer

                        commandList = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(vbLf)

                        For i = LBound(commandList) To UBound(commandList)

                            Dim wsh As Object
                            wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                            Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean : waitOnReturn = True
                            Dim windowStyle As Integer : windowStyle = 0
                            Dim errorCode As Integer

                            wsh.Run("cmd /C echo ----------" & (commandList(i)) & "------------ >> output.txt", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

                            errorCode = wsh.Run("cmd /C " & (commandList(i)) & " >> output.txt", windowStyle, waitOnReturn)

                            If errorCode = 0 Then

                            Else
                                MsgBox((commandList(i)) & " exited with error code " & errorCode & ".")
                            End If



                        Next

                    End If
                End If


                Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()

                MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("contact@rawlingsbm.com")

                MyMailMessage.To.Add("rbmcontactapp@gmail.com")

                MyMailMessage.Subject = "RBM Contact Application"
                MyMailMessage.Body = "Person: " & TextBox1.Text & vbCrLf & "Phone: " & TextBox2.Text & vbCrLf & "Message: " & vbCrLf & RichTextBox1.Text


                Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
                SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("rbmcontactapp", "PASSWORD_GOES_HERE")
                SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
                SMTPServer.Port = 587

                Try
                    ' SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)
                    MessageBox.Show("Thanks! We've Got the Message and We'll be in touch soon.")
                    Application.Exit()
                Catch ex As SmtpException
                    MessageBox.Show("Ooops. Something isn't working right. Please try again in just a moment.")
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
                End Try
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all of the form before sending your message. Thanks!")
                Button1.Visible = True
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all of the form before sending your message. Thanks!")
            Button1.Visible = True
        End If

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill out all of the form before sending your message. Thanks!")
        Button1.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub

Private Function Split(ByVal commandList As String(), ByVal vbLf As String) As String
    Throw New NotImplementedException
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual code? I see two major errors without even having to strain my eyes :)

Comment: What are the two major errors?

Comment: `wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` You are not using `Set` and secondly you have brackets in `wsh.Run("cmd...)`

Comment: Ok. Well, the different commands I pass to the cmd prompt through the GUI that I've built, work fine. Its just the formatting issues that I am having with the WMIC commands... Is there anything you know of that I could check for, or wmic parameter that I need to pass? I've searched and searched and can't find anything. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you `first` update your question with the `exact` code that you are using which is giving you a different formatting so that I can test it before commenting?

Comment: Also attach a screenshot for both scenarios which depict what were you expecting and what is different.

Comment: ok. Working on that now. I just want to say, that Im a PHP programmer... not a VBA programmer... lol. I just wanted to get that off my chest... :)  I will post the screenshots here in just one moment.

Comment: After seeing your code, my first comment doesn't hold any good because your edit now shows that the code was written in VB.Net and not VBA. Please note that both are different. Do you want to do this in `VBA` or `VB.Net`

Comment: VB.Net.  Im new to this type of programming.... (Obviously...)  And here are links to the screenshots ... http://imgur.com/HyakC53 http://imgur.com/kCZkMua http://imgur.com/VJCXxYj http://imgur.com/jC9Ykqz http://imgur.com/GfN3gqH

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43446/discussion-between-daniel-sikes-and-siddharth-rout)